# Where the ffmpeg.exe is located in when downloading the archive?

Tags: ffmpeg

I went to the official site:

[ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)

I downloaded first the windows build version then i downloaded the ffmpeg-2.8.3.tar.bz2 file in both i didn't find the exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm very curious what Windows build you found that didn't contain a ffmpeg.exe.

[ffmpeg.org](https://ffmpeg.org) links to http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/, where you can find Windows builds.

If you are not sure whether you should use the 32bit or 64bit version, please check what type of Windows you are currently running.

Still not sure? The static 32bit version should work on both 32bit and 64bit Windows.

[edit]
Zeranoe currently automatically selects the recommended build for you :-)